# Is there any concept of shiva margi ekadashi in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, ekadashi

My question is which ekadashi to follow shaiva margi or vaishnav margi?

For eg :- 26-2-2022 is ekadashi according to shaiva followers
And
27-2-2022 is ekadashi according to vaishnav followers!

Comment: Nothing like Shiva margi Ekadashi but Smarthas and Vaishnavas may follow different calendars (Panjika) and which leads to different Ekadashi dates for the two sects.

Comment: See this blog post --- https://www.hindu-blog.com/2010/04/smarta-ekadasi-what-is-smartha-ekadashi.html

Comment: @Rickross so which is correct ekadashi?

Comment: Not sure but Vaishnvas will follow their own calendar and the others (Smarthas) won't follow the Vaishnavas' calendar. So, they will fast on different days. Difficult to say which one is the correct day.

Comment: Best to follow the Panjikas followed in your region if you are observing the fast.

Comment: @Harsh, the scriptures themselves prescribe different ways (timing/duration) for Ekadashi-fastings for Smartas, and Vaishnavas. Even in that - there's sometimes a variation amongst various Vaisnava sects, especially the Sri Vaisnava and the Gaudiya. So there's no fixed method to observe the Ekadashi fast, unform across all sects.